# yarn build command not found Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

COPY client/package.json client/
COPY client/yarn.lock client/
RUN yarn install

COPY server/package.json server/
COPY server/yarn.lock server/
RUN yarn install

COPY client/ client/
RUN yarn build <--- Error here
COPY server/ server/

USER node
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

I have 3 package.json files, one for the app directory, and one for each of the client and server directories. The build command is found in the client package.json (below):

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "ethers": "5.4.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run `docker build -t myApp .` from the /app directory, I keep getting back `error Command "build" not found`. I followed a tutorial on Udemy that did something similar and it worked, and that tutorial didn't have the build script in the /app package.json either, so I don't believe that is where my error is coming from. I'm pretty new to docker, so any help on what I can do to get the app to compile would be appreciated.

Comment: You never change the `WORKDIR`, so you're running three `yarn` commands all in the top-level directory.  (If you have three separate applications here, should they be in three different images?)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, if the package.json of client is under app/clinet then you need `WORKDIR /app/client` before `RUN yarn install`